# Regular Expression to Extract IP Address and Port from Oracle Connection Descriptor

Tags: java, regex

Can any one please help me to get `regex` pattern string (java) to extract ip address and port in below string.

```
(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=199.888.88.88)(PORT=8080))
```

I'm first trying regular expression.

Comment: Read regex.. you will understand.

Comment: Put the code you have tried so far

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: That won't work

Comment: @0A0D I read extract the pattern and saw OP put the word jdbc in bold

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Must have been before the code was put into a block because when you add double underlines it bolds the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    String s = "(HOST=jdbc)(USER=))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=199.888.88.88)(PORT=8080))";
    String ip = s.replaceAll("(?i).+\\(HOST\\s*=\\s*(.+?)\\).+", "$1");
    String port = s.replaceAll("(?i).+\\(PORT\\s*=\\s*(.+?)\\).+", "$1");
    System.out.println(ip);
    System.out.println(port);
```

output

```
199.888.88.88
8080
```

note that (?i) makes it case-insensitive

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
HOST=([\d.]+).+?PORT=(\d+)
```